# Pandas DataFrame pivot reset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and applying a pivot on that but the output is not as expected.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    raw_data = {
            'PRODUCT': ['Display', 'InStream', 'Mobile'],
            'BLAZE_TAG_NAME_DESC': ['enewsletter', 'get_the_guide', 'logo'], 
            'CLICKTHRU': [19,30,40],
            'INTERACTION':[30,40,50]}
    df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['PRODUCT', 'BLAZE_TAG_NAME_DESC', 'CLICKTHRU','INTERACTION'])

    df_b = pd.pivot_table(df_a,index="PRODUCT",columns="BLAZE_TAG_NAME_DESC",values=['CLICKTHRU','INTERACTION'],aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value = 0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

I want the output is like

[image]

I tried the trick reset index. but that's not working

```
df.reset_index()
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the columns names with `None`

```
df_b.columns.names=[None,None]
df_b
Out[54]: 
           CLICKTHRU                    INTERACTION                   
         enewsletter get_the_guide logo enewsletter get_the_guide logo
PRODUCT                                                               
Display           19             0    0          30             0    0
InStream           0            30    0           0            40    0
Mobile             0             0   40           0             0   50
```

Comment: Inline copy `df_b.rename_axis([None] * 2, 1)`

Comment: @piRSquared great tips sir

Comment: @Wen How can I delete the index "product" from that output?. rest will be same.

Comment: @MonikaRai df.index.names=None